# Magento 2.4.2: Google recaptcha not working on Braintree credit form

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2, braintree, google-recaptcha

I am having a serious issue. I use the default Magento 2.4.2 google Recaptcha and it applied to the Braintree credit form at checkout.

Recaptcha showing but not working validation. They pass every time.

Any workaround or solution would be really appreciated. After many hours I still cannot make it work. Thanks.

Comment: Is this still a problem? I finally determined that my plugin on checkout recaptcha validation is failing because validation is happening everywhere except on checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing, but instead on checkout, it was on the admin panel login. My ad blocker was blocking it from working correctly.

Also, have you set the minimum score threshold to a suitable level?

Comment: Where to set the minimum score threshold to a suitable level?

Comment: There is currently an issue open for this:

* https://github.com/genecommerce/module-braintree-magento2/pull/164